# How to append multiple lines to a file, if these lines doesn't exist in that file?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, deduplication

How to append multiple lines to a file, if these lines doesn't exist in that file?

For example, to add multiple global aliases to `/etc/bash.bashrc` I use an [heredocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
cat <<-"BASHRC" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
    alias rss="/etc/init.d/php*-fpm restart && systemctl restart nginx.service"
    alias brc="nano /etc/bash.bashrc"
BASHRC
```

I was criticized that this operation doesn't include a way to check if the lines are already there, and if mistakenly rexecute the heredocument, I could cause redundancy, as well as conflict.

Comment: How sure can you be that the lines in the file and the new ones are exactly the same?

Comment: I cannot, or maybe I can but it will be an extremely complicated mechanism.

Comment: Well, you could grep for `alias rss=` and only add the line of you don‘t get a match. Same for each other alias you want to add. This still doesn‘t cover situations where a user has a separate file for aliases which gets sourced by .bashrc

Comment: This was cross-posted at [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994559/add-multiple-aliases-to-etc-bash-bashrc-aliases-if-they-arent-already-there/994620#994620), and I wrote an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/994620/732822) which was already accepted by the OP there.

Comment: You are quite correct @MukeshSaiKumar. Although there I asked only on aliases to find out if my approach of adding aliases is wrong. Here I desired a general one-line solution and brought aliases only as an example. But given your answer there it's likely I was wrong to publish this question here and answers should be migrated to there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple shell script to add lines from the file `newdata` to `datafile`. It should be straightforward to change `newdata` to a here-doc. This is really not very effective since it calls `grep` for every (new) input line:

```
target=datafile
while IFS= read -r line ; do
    if ! grep -Fqxe "$line" "$target" ; then
        printf "%s\n" "$line" >> "$target"
    fi
done < newdata
```

For each line, we use `grep` to see if it already exists in the target file, `-F` for fixed-string match (no regexes), `-x` for full line match, and `-q` to suppress output of matched lines. `grep` returns a falsy error code if it doesn't find a matching line, so append to target file if the negated result is truthy.

---

More effectively, in `awk`. This relies on `awk` being able handle arbitrary lines as keys to an array.

```
$ awk 'FNR == NR { lines[$0] = 1; next } ! ($0 in lines) {print}' datafile newdata
```

The first part `FNR == NR { lines[$0] = 1; next }` loads all lines of the first input file as keys into the (associative) array `lines`. The second part `! ($0 in lines) {print}` runs on following input lines, and prints the line if it's not in the array, i.e. the "new" lines.

The resulting output contains the new lines, only, so it needs to be appended to the original file, e.g. with `sponge`:

```
$ awk 'FNR == NR { lines[$0] = 1; next } ! ($0 in lines) {print}' datafile newdata | sponge -a datafile
```

Or we could have `awk` append the lines to the final line, it just requires passing the file name to `awk`:

```
$ target=datafile 
$ awk -vtarget="$target" 'FNR == NR { lines[$0] = 1; next } 
                        ! ($0 in lines) {print >> target}' "$target" newdata
```

To use a here-doc with `awk`, we'll need to add `-` (stdin) as an explicit source file, in addition to setting the redirection, so `awk ... "$target" - <<EOF`

Answer (score 3):

This solution is probably a little different than what you had in mind but I'd check whether an alias is actually defined and only add it to bashrc if it isn't. Assuming you are using a relatively current version of Bash...

```
# instead of 'alias x=y' form put them in an associative array
declare -A aliases
aliases['a']='apple'
aliases['ba']='banana'

for key in "${!aliases[@]}"; do
    if ! alias "$key" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        printf "alias %s='%s'\n" "$key" "${aliases[$key]}" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
done

unset aliases key
```

Source this `. ./scriptname` rather than run it as a normal script.

**Note:** If you have a bunch of the candidate aliases and are wary of manually converting them to associative array form then you c edit the file with `vim` and run this commmand: `:%s/\valias  *([^=]+)\=['"]?([^'"]+)['"]?$/aliases['\1']='\2'/`.

*OR* put your candidate aliases (and nothing else) in a file (e.g. `/tmp/aliases.txt`) and replace the `aliases[..]='..'` lines in the script with this:

```
while IFS= read -r a; do 
    eval "$a"; 
done < <(sed -E "s/alias  *([^=]+)=['\"]?([^'\"]+)['\"]?$/aliases['\1']='\2'/" /tmp/aliases.txt)
```

Of course, there are other ways besides using AAs but they're clean and easy to work with...and I'm all in at this point. :)

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution for exact matches (not optimized for performance); the file `input` contains the lines to be checked for:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { lines[NR]=$0; next; };
    { for(i=1;i<=length(lines);i++) if ($0==lines[i]) matches[i]=1; print; };
    END { for(i=1;i<=length(lines);i++)
        if (matches[i]==0) print lines[i]; }' input file
```

Testing:

```
:> cat input
alias rss="/etc/init.d/php*-fpm restart && systemctl restart nginx.service"
alias brc="nano /etc/bash.bashrc"

:> cat file
a
b
c
alias rss="/etc/init.d/php*-fpm restart && systemctl restart nginx.service"
d
```

Output of the `awk` command:

```
a
b
c
alias rss="/etc/init.d/php*-fpm restart && systemctl restart nginx.service"
d
alias brc="nano /etc/bash.bashrc"
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the order of appended lines matter?

If no, you can try such a solution:

```
comm -1 -3 <(sort /etc/bash.bashrc) <(sort aliases) >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

assuming you have previously saved lines to add in the file `aliases`.

`comm` is GNU [coreutil](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#comm-invocation) (you can see the man page for it), which allows comparing two sorted files line by line.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm. How about this...

Put the aliases to add in file *new*. Then...

```
cp bashrc bashrc.tmp && comm -23 <(sort -u new) <(sort -u bashrc.tmp) >> bashrc && rm -f bashrc.tmp
```

We unique sort both the new aliases and the *bashrc* contents (put in a temp file to avoid race condition when we append to *bashrc*) and run them through `comm`. `comm` does line-by-line comparisons of sorted files and shows unique and common lines. We suppress columns 2 and 3 (`-23`) so the result is simply those lines that are unique to *new* and we append those to *bashrc*. That's it.

*(This is a totally different approach than my other answer, focusing on your quest for more of a "one-liner".)*

Answer (score 0):

```
filename='openFileLimit.txt'
while read p; do
    if grep "$p" /target/file/and/path; then
            echo "$p already present"
    else
            echo "$p" >> /target/file/and/path
    fi
done < $filename
```